# How to configure memcache on PHP 8 with Windows IIS server

Tags: php, memcached

Recently I upgraded PHP to v8.0 and I couldn't able to configure the Memcache for the same. Earlier to this Memcache was working fine on PHP 7.4.
I tried to download the latest Memcached from https://pecl.php.net/package/memcached and extracted it into c:/memcached and tried to run the memcached.exe -d install & memcached.exe -d start but was not able to run them, as it returns

```
'memcached.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Anyone help me with clear steps to install Memcache for PHP 8 on the Windows IIS server?

Answer (score 0):

I just placed a compatible memcache.ddl file and it worked.
Here are the various version-specific memcache.dll files you will get.

https://github.com/nono303/PHP-memcache-dll